# Omniauth facebook ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, facebook-login

Currently my "login with facebook" button works perfectly when the browsers hits `/auth/facebook`. However, I would prefer to be able to have a user login without refreshing the page. I'm trying something like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $login;
  $login = $('#login');
  return $login.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Trying to log in");
    return $.ajax({
      url: $login.attr('href'),
      data: {},
      complete: function(response) {
        return console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

but I don't seem to get useful data back from the response, and the browser seems to cancel the redirect (according to the web developer panel in chrome). Is there any way to get this working with omniauth?

I don't want to use Iframes either.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to do it you need to understand how omniauth works. Then you will be able to choose most appropriate solution.